# Call a method through reflection fails

Tags: c#, reflection, getmethod

I try to call a method using reflection but method is not called. Below is my code:

```
private abstract class A<T>
{
    public abstract void DoSomething(string asd, T obj);
}

private class MyClass : A<int>
{
    public override void DoSomething(string asd, int obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type unboundGenericType = typeof(A<>);
    Type boundGenericType = unboundGenericType.MakeGenericType(typeof(int));
    MethodInfo doSomethingMethod = boundGenericType.GetMethod("DoSomething");
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(boundGenericType);
    doSomethingMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] {"Hello", 123});
}
```

I also tried to call the usual method, but also errors :(.

Comment: `typeof(A<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int))` creates a `A<int>`, but `A<int>` is an abstract class. `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(A<int>))` is not possible therefor. Changing this around to use `MyClass` will actually work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/j7r96C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You retrieve the method on a wrong type. The method `DoSomething` has been implemented in `MyClass` and not on the generic type you bound.

If you try the following, you will the result you are looking for:

```
Type myClass = typeof(MyClass);
MethodInfo doSomethingMethod = myClass.GetMethod("DoSomething");
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myClass);
doSomethingMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { "Hello", 123 });
```